# Easy Javascript Regex Question

Tags: javascript, regex

Why doesn't this assign prepClass to the string selectorClass with underscores instead of non alpha chars? What do I need to change it to?

```
var regex = new RegExp("/W/", "g");
var prepClass = selectorClass.replace(regex, "_");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things:

- If you use the `RegExp` constructor, you don't need the slashes, you are maybe confusing it with the syntax of `RegExp` literals.
- You want match the `\W` character class.

The following will work:

```
var regex = new RegExp("\\W", "g");
```

The `RegExp` constructor accepts a string containing the pattern, note that you should *double escape* the slash, in order to get a single slash and a W (`"\W"`) in the string.

Or you could simply use the literal notation:

```
var regex = /\W/g;
```

Recommended read:

- [Regular Expressions (MDC)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/core_javascript_1.5_guide/regular_expressions)

Comment: Correctamundo. Thanks. I'll accept as soon as the time limit is up

Comment: Side question - can I just use /\W/g inside replace rather than defining a variable regex?

Comment: @Matrym: Yes, you can use either directly in the replace: `.replace(new RegExp("\\W", "g"), "_")` or `.replace(/\W/g, "_")`.